# Google Maps iOS SDK doesn't update in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uitableview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I run google maps ios SDK on normal view controller, and it runs perfectly, it even shows the current location but I decided to put into a `tableViewCell`, the code below will show how

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class GMapTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, GMSMapViewDelegate  {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }


    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }



}


extension GMapTableViewCell: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        }
    }
}
```

What this code does is simply add a google maps `delegate` and extend a `CLLocationManagerDelegate`. In the extension, this is where it supposed to update the device's current location, again it works perfectly in normal `UIView` but not here.

Code in the tableView

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let reuseIdentifier = "maps"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GMapTableViewCell
            // I inherit both GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, for tableView 
            cell.locationManager.delegate = self
            cell.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            cell.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            cell.mapView.delegate = self
            cell.mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            cell.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

            return cell
    }
```

I have no idea what did I do wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right now, could not place any marker of a map inside `UITableViewCell`.

I have found out, that Google Maps works in `UITableViewCell` only if it's methods are called in `awakeFromNib` method of a cell.

I did not figure out why, but found out it just now.